# About calc RSI/RCI in Mulitimeframe(request.security) in pine-script

Tags: pine-script, stock, tradingview-api

**This question is a question of pine-script in TradingView.*

I'd like to calc RSI and RCI of 5min chart in 1min chart.(Mulitimeframe)

I run the following code. However RSI, RCI value is different greatly in 5min chart's those.
Calculation process is same as 5min chart.

**pine-script in 1min chart**

```
close5m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', close)
rsi5m = ta.rsi(close5m, 14)
```

> "rsi5m" is different greatly from 5min chart's those.

Please tell me reason or how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, you are getting the close price from the 5 minute but trying to calculate the rsi value on 1 min chart using 5m close price as a source.

You can actually pass functions as expression to your `security()` call.

```
rsi_1m = ta.rsi(close, 14)
rsi5m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '5', rsi_1m)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I could fix by the above advice. I was able to correct my understanding of "request.security" specification.